# Can I use an older version of Myth with newer versions of its dependencies?

Tags: css, postcss, autoprefixer

We're using this outdated preprocessor called [Myth](https://github.com/segmentio/myth), which uses a deprecated version of autoprefixer, and a very old version of postcss. "autoprefixer-core": "5.2.1" and "postcss": "4.1.16". Is it possible to update the deprecated dependency to the new (autoprefix), and update the old version of postcss to the latest version, while still using the Myth preprocessor, or will this break Myth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork Myth, update the dependencies and run the test again. If everything is fine, you can use your fork of Myth.